# Update fails with namespaced model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, namespaces

I have an update form in Rails 3 for admin users that fails silently, despite having validations. It *was* working previously, but when I moved everything to a namespace, it no longer saves.

Here is the relevant code from my controller:

```
def update
    @admin = Admin::Admin.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @admin.update_attributes(params[:admin])
            flash[:success] = "'#{@admin.name}' was successfully updated."
            format.html { redirect_to admin_admins_path }
        else
            format.html { render action: "edit" }
        end
    end
end
```

And the model (unfinished, but previously working):

```
class Admin::Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :name,   :presence=>{:message=>"Name can't be blank"}
    validates :email,   :presence=>{:message=>"Email can't be blank"},
        :length => {:minimum => 3, :maximum => 254, :message=>"Email must be between 3 and 254 characters"},
        :uniqueness=>{:message=>"Email has already been registered"},
        :format=>{:with=>/^([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message=>"Email must be a valid email format"}
    validates :password,   :presence=>{:message=>"Password can't be blank"}
end
```

And the first part of the form partial:

```
<%= form_for(@admin) do |f| %>
```

Everything loads properly, but when I try to save, my validations are ignored and it redirects to the index page with a success message, but without saving the data. I have a feeling I'm missing something to do with namespaces, but I'm not completely sure what the problem is. Could it be looking for the model in the base model directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you inspect the params? I could imagine that `params[:admin]` does not contain the forms values anymore.

Comment: That's correct, they're blank. I think it's a namespace issue because no validations are run.

Comment: Validations are not complaining about `@admin.update_attributes(nil)`.

Comment: Try to find out how the Admin::Admin model is used in params instead. Didn't test it but I could imagine something like `params['admin::admin'].

Comment: Close: params[admin_admin] was what finally worked. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, VirtuosiMedia and I stepped through it, and RoR adds an "admin_" to represent the Admin:: namespace, so we had to look for params[:admin_admin].